# Background Div Images not displaying when setting them via Inline Styles Dynamically | Next.Js

Tags: css, reactjs, image, next.js

I am trying to render my images from a component by using a map and external js file to store images as objects, then set loop through them to set it as a different background image for every div created if that makes sense. I will provide code to make it clearer on what I am trying to accomplish, during the map process I am trying to target an objects method but I believe it does not work since none of my images are displaying.

Component File: WorkImages.js

```
export default function WorkImage({workImages}) {
    return (
        <div>
            {
                workImages.map((work) => {
                    return (
                        <div style={{backgroundImage: `url(${work.image})` }} id='work-img' className='work-img' key={work.id}>
                                <a href=""><div className="overlay">View Work</div></a>
                        </div>
                    );
                })
            }
        </div>
    )
}
```

Object File Where I am Retrieving the images from when looping (image.js):
`import img1 from '../public/images/filler1.jpg'`
`import img2 from '../public/images/filler2.jpg'`
`import img3 from '../public/images/filler3.jpg'`

```
const image = [
    {
        id: 1,
        image: img1
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        image: img2
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        image: img3
    }
]

export default image;
```

Main File Where I am trying to render out the divs with the dynamic background images (Work.js):
`import Aos from 'aos'`
`import 'aos/dist/aos.css'`
`import {useEffect, useState} from 'react'`
`import WorkImage from './WorkImage';`
`import image from './image'`

```
export default function Work() {
    const [workImages, setImage] = useState(image);
    useEffect(() => {
        Aos.init({duration: 2000});
    }, []); 
    return (
        <section id='work' className='work-section'>
            <div data-aos='fade-left'>
                <h1 className="work-header">- RECENT WORK -</h1>
                <div className="showcase-wrapper">
                    <WorkImage workImages={workImages} />
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your images object to:

```js
const images = [
    {
        id: 1,
        image: '/images/filler1.jpg'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        image: '/images/filler2.jpg'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        image: '/images/filler3.jpg'
    }
]

export default images;
```

There is no need to `import` images if they are already in `public` directory.

Refer: [Static File Serving](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving)

---

For those who are facing similar problem and not using the `public` directory:

When you do something like this `import img from 'path/to/img.ext'`, `img` is not the source, it is an object of type `StaticImageData`, which is defined like:

```
type StaticImageData = {
  src: string;
  height: number;
  width: number;
  placeholder?: string;
};
```

So, in such cases you need to use `img.src` for the URL. Something like this will also work for you instead of the above resolution:

```js
{backgroundImage: `url(${work.image.src})` }
```

---

Also, in this particular code, there isn't any need to have an images object as the files are named properly in order. Something like this should have also worked:

```js
Array.from({ length: 3 }, (_, i) => i + 1).map((i) => (
  <div
    style={{ backgroundImage: `url(/images/filler${i}.jpg)` }}
    id={`work-img-${i}`}
    className='work-img'
    key={`work-${i}`}
  >
    <a href='/'>
      <div className='overlay'>View Work</div>
    </a>
  </div>
));
```

PS: Change your `id` and `key` in `map`. You were setting the same `id` for multiple elements, and also setting index as `key` is not recommended.