# TypeScript linter error when loading image in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, lint

I have a React app with Next.js where I import an image using:

```
import image1 from '../../../img/dummy-image-2.jpg';
```

Later on I use:

```
<img src={image1} alt="Dummy" />
```

The app builds and runs as expected (the image is shown) but I'm getting a linter error on the `src` attribute in the `<img>` tag that reads:

```
Type 'StaticImageData' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

How can I get rid of this error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Background Div Images not displaying when setting them via Inline Styles Dynamically | Next.Js](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68517270/11613622) -- refer the second section of the answer. Basically do `src={image1.src}`

Comment: @brc-dd unfortunately it doesn't. I don't have images in the `/public` folder. Also when I import my images they are imported as a `string` and that's the problem, I'm importing a `string` but the TypeScript linter believes that I'm importing a `StaticImageData`. `src={image1.src}` renders nothing however `src={image1}` does renders the image.

Comment: Okay, so you have a custom webpack config (or are using some plugin) where you have configured a loader for the images. In that case you need to [disable the static image optimization in next.config.js](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/image-optimization#disable-static-imports). It'll prevent Next.js from adding a reference to `next/image-types/global` in `next-env.d.ts`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file named `assets.d.ts`, if you don't already have a `.d.ts` file in you project and put the following:

```
declare module '*.jpg' {
  const content: any; // you can also set this to string
  export default content;
}
```

[See this link if you want to know more about `.d.ts` files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21247278/about-d-ts-in-typescript)

Comment: I added it to my `declaration.d.ts` file but the error still shows up.

Comment: I had a similar error and this is what did it for me.  Sorry I can't help more than this.